# Multiple assemblies and MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, routes

I have a solution (.Net 4.6) made up of multiple projects each with their own MVC controllers and api controllers.

I'm using  attribute routing :

config.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

All my MVC controllers work correctly, but only the APIs in my main startup project register.

It's strange because the MVC controllers work, but in the same assembly the API controllers don't.

Is the registration handled differently?
What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I lost a lot of time to this trying to figure out what the issue was. In the end I created custom assembly loader to replace the default one.

When I set a break point on this I could see I had a stale assembly in the temporary files which was preventing the correct routes to load.

It now all works out of the box with no extra code as I thought it should!

Comment: I had the same issue.  I would have thought that the MapHttpAttributeRoutes() would simply have been looking for controllers in assemblies in the bin folder, or at the very least, loaded into the domain, but no, seems to be looking somewhere else (temp files) which is rather annoying.  Frameworks; they give with one hand, they take away with the other...